# Ruby array element evaluation

Tags: arrays, ruby, operator-precedence

I like to know why in arrays when an element is a method call the existence of parentheses matters. I understand `[]` is a method call and I assumed the arguments to that method call would be evaluated first, so the existence of the parentheses shouldn't matter. But clearly it matters.

```
def double x
  x * 2
end

a = [1, 2+2] # works fine the array is [1, 4]
b = [1, double(2)] # also works fine the array is [1, 4]
c = [1, (double 2)] # also works fine the array is [1, 4]
d = [1, double 2]  # throws error syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
[1, double 2]
```

Comment: `[foo 1, 2, 3]` – are `2` and `3` additional method arguments or array elements?

Comment: I get what you mean. Thanks! When looking at this for an element in the first position this is very clear, but when it is the last element its less obvious.

Comment: On the other hand, `[1, a: 2, b: 3]` is happily accepted by the parser even though it's also ambiguous (could be `[1, {a: 2, b: 3}]` or `[1, {a: 2}, {b: 3}]`) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Stefan what is the ambiguity in `[1, double 2]`, to me it seems unambiguous, but maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @LesNightingill there is none. Ruby is inconsistent.